# Reduction of the harmonic currents in LCC HVDC systems

Tags: converter, harmonics, hvdc

[image]Why there is a reduction of the harmonic currents in the AC side in an LCC HVDC system?
Here is represented the  AC current in yellow, in red the DC voltage and the sinusoidal waves are the AC voltages. As you can see, the AC current is not a simple step but is smoothed. Why has that behavior?

Comment: Show the rectified current pulses define the HVDC load  capacitance and then examine the pulse width of current

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 since we are in DC, the rectified current pulses are equal to the voltage ones shown in the figure. About the load capacitance, it is sufficient to say that it is constant considering constant frequency.

Comment: That is incorrect. Current is defined when ithe rectifier conducts when VHDC is less than VHAC then Ic=Cdv/dt so for 10% ripple induced the current crest factor Peak / average is 10x

Comment: Might be useful to list (link to) the source you're working from (to show the diagram in its original context).

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you so much Tony! It's clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is incorrect to assume the current is sinusoidal.

Current is defined when rectifier conducts when VHDC is less than VHAC ie. when the rectifiers are forward biased.

Knowing Ic=Cdv/dt and Resistive damping results in ripple . I do not know the ripple specs but for 10% ripple induced the current crest factor Peak / average is 10x. More rectified phases raises the average so the crest factor ratio and harmonics reduce.

The line impedance affects conduction pulses so reactor  filtering is required and harmonics are now > 6x line frequency must be controlled.  This may include notch filters near the 11th or 12th harmonic.

### Anecdotal

I am not an expert in HVDC yet this observation comes from fundamentals. (I am an expert in PD however on HV transformers and stuff alike) When I was a student in Winnipeg, I used to vacuum the ceiling of the 7 story scaffolding inside  Dorsey HVDC station to remove construction dust (very low levels already) with portable battery backpack vacuum machines to do the ceiling. This was to reduce the risk of Partial Discharge(PD). I also operated the wet-vac floor cleaners and applied concrete sealer daily. At that time English Electric was the primary contractor and they used Mercury valves 2m tall to operate as inverters.

Comment: Sorry Tony, I have another little question: are the AC current harmonics reduced only at the AC side of the receiving end right? Not even at the AC sending side?

Comment: I have no experience in HVDC filters, but it becomes a complex transmission line theory matched filter problem at sending end with matching at receiving end as well. Perhaps @winny or some HVDC Eng can pipe in. there many papers on this subject.